# What happens when I type `int a = a;`?

Tags: c++

How does the compiler interpret the following code:

```cpp
int a = a;
```

without any previously defined variable named `a`? Why doesn't the compiler report error here?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and you'll probably get something. I don't know offhand whether Clang has a specific warning for this, but GCC and MSVC both warn with blanket options.

Comment: See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.scope.pdecl#1.